# How to fix "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment'"

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm facing an issue in my code that I can't find how to fix.
I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined - jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

Here is my code :

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/getPvaSession.php'
    }).done(function (data) {
        let content = data['content'];
        console.log(content);
        $('body').append('<table id="table"></table>');
        for (let i=0;i<content[i].length;++i) {
            $('table').append('<tr id="' + i + '"></tr>');
            for (let j=0; j<content.length; ++j){
                $(i).append('<td id="' + i + '_' + j + '">' + content[i][j] + '</td>')
            }
        }
    })
```

My console.log shows this (It is a simple matrix):

```
(8) [Array(31), Array(31), Array(31), Array(31), Array(31), Array(31), Array(31), Array(31)]
0: (31) ["Projet", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]
1: (31) ["Administrateur Réseau", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "1", "1", "0.5", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "1", "1"]
2: (31) ["Intercontrat", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0.5", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
3: (31) ["Formation", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
4: (31) ["Congés payés", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
5: (31) ["Congés sans solde", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
6: (31) ["Incentive", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
7: (31) ["Maladie", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
length: 8
```

I read online that many people faced this error using `this` the wrong way, but I'm not using it anywhere.

Could you clarify it? And explain the error if possible so I won't do the mistake next time.
Thanks!

Comment: maybe your append is not working correctly? If so, try creating elements with var table = document.createElement('table'), add id attribute, and then do appendChild(table) on body (same for all elements you want to append)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop thru the outer array as `content.length` and not `content[0].length`. and use `content[0].length` in the inner array.

Like:

```js
var content = [["Administrateur Réseau","1","1","1","1","1","","","1","1","0.5","","","","","1","1","1","1","1","","","","1","1","1","1","","","1","1"],["Intercontrat","","","","","","","","","","0.5","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Formation","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Congés payés","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Congés sans solde","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Incentive","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Maladie","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]]

$('body').append('<table id="table"></table>');
for (let i = 0; i < content.length; ++i) {                       //Remove the [i]. This will loop thru all contents   
  var tr = $('<tr id="' + i + '"></tr>');                        //Create a tr element and store on a variable
  $('table').append(tr);
  for (let j = 0; j < content[i].length; ++j) {                  //Add the [i]. This will loop thru the inner array
    tr.append('<td id="' + i + '_' + j + '">' + content[i][j] + '</td>'); //Append the td string on tr variable
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another option is to construct an HTML string. And use that to append in the body

```js
var content = [["Administrateur Réseau","1","1","1","1","1","","","1","1","0.5","","","","","1","1","1","1","1","","","","1","1","1","1","","","1","1"],["Intercontrat","","","","","","","","","","0.5","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Formation","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Congés payés","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Congés sans solde","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Incentive","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],["Maladie","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]]


var html = "";

html += "<table>";
for (let i = 0; i < content.length; ++i) {
  html += "<tr id='" + i + "'>";
  for (let j = 0; j < content[i].length; ++j) {
    html += '<td id="' + i + '_' + j + '">' + content[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</table>";

$('body').append(html);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```